# How to Validate a Form using the Functions I created

Tags: javascript, forms, validation

I have created functions to validate my form. But I want them all to run at once when I click the submit button. So, I have a formValidate function, and then I have a firstNameValidate, lastNameValidate ect.

My question is, how would I create the formValidate function to run the functions i have, but ONLY submit the form if all of them are true?

```
function firstNameValidate() {
    // Making sure that the firstname input is not blank
    if (firstName.value.length == 0) {
        // If the firstname input is blank, then return the error text below
        error.innerHTML = 'Please Enter a Valid First Name, Cannot be Blank';
        // Error text css class
        error.className = 'error';
        // Making sure that the browser window focuses on the error
        firstName.focus();
        // Does not let the browser submit the form
        //  this statement makes sure that the input has only letters
        return false;
    } else if (!firstName.value.match(letter)) {
        // // If the input has something other then numbers, show this error.
        error.innerHTML =
            'Please Enter a Valid First Name, Cannot contain characters(!@#) or numbers';
        // // error text css class
        error.className = 'error';
        // browser window focuses on error
        firstName.focus();
        // Form does not submit
        return false;
    }
    if (firstName.value.length > 0 && firstName.value.match(letter)) {
        error.className = '';
        error.innerHTML = '';
        return true;
    }
}
```

I can get the first name and last name to validate, however if one them is filled out it sends the form. So the return true and return false I think are wrong.

Comment: that should be the default situation: you check every single field, and `return false;` if not valid, then, in the end, you `return true;`. That means, if you encounter ANY validation error, always return false, otherwise return true.

Comment: 1. no need for the last if. 2. `document.querySelector("form").onsubmit = function() { return firstNameValidate() && otherValidate() && yetAnotherValidate() }` - also look into `addEventListener`

Comment: So the if statement should say that if the function returns false, then return false and at the end it should have a return true? this kind of works. But if the user hits the submit button and all the fields are not filled out, then just the very first error message appears. anyway to show them all?

Comment: If you dont need very specific tests in these functions you can use the build in validation like <input type="text" required /> = Not empty or <input type="text"  pattern="^$[0-9]{5}"/> = must be 5 Numbers

Comment: If statements are meant to be used in certain conditions as this. `if(firstNameValidator() && lastNameValidator() && otherValidator())` then submit your form.

Comment: I tried this if(firstNameValidate() && lastNameValidate()){ return true;} and it submited the form anyway. something Im doing wrong?

Comment: Look in the console for errors. Any error will submit the form

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
function firstNameValidate() {

  if (firstName.value.length == 0) {
    error.innerHTML = 'Please Enter a Valid First Name, Cannot be Blank';
    error.className = 'error';
    firstName.focus();
    return false;
  }
  if (!firstName.value.match(letter)) {
    error.innerHTML = 'Please Enter a Valid First Name, Cannot contain characters(!@#) or numbers';
    error.className = 'error';
    firstName.focus();
    return false;
  } else {
    //intended code goes here , or simply return true.
  }

}
```

If you want to do strict checking then write all the validation in if statement, and if everything is filled properly then do the correct code in an else statement,

and call the above function on form onsubmit or on a button click it will do the work..

Hope this helps ..!!

Comment: This makes sense to me, I have a function called formValidate that is called on submit. With the else statement as return true;, the form submits and displays the error. Im using a mailto: action is that the problem?